# Neo4j multidimensional search

Tags: search, neo4j

I'm trying to develop a Neo4j search query to find similar looking photos.

I have 62 nodes labeled "Likeness" that represent photos that all other nodes labeled "Photo" will be compared to. My data looks like this:

```
(p:Photo {name: 'treehouse'})-[r:LOOKS_LIKE {weight: 0.874655}]->(l:Likeness {name: 'lighthouse'})
(p:Photo {name: 'cat'})-[r:LOOKS_LIKE {weight: 0.00454}]->(l:Likeness {name: 'lighthouse'})
(p:Photo {name: 'house'})-[r:LOOKS_LIKE {weight: 0.4768}]->(l:Likeness {name: 'lighthouse'})
etc...
```

All relationship weights are between 0 and 1.

So an example search might be:

```
[
{name: 'lighthouse', value: 0.856378},
{name: 'car', value: 0.17854},
{name: 'tank', value: 0.034523},
{name: 'pencil', value: 0.078902}
]
```

How do I return nodes in order of similarity (distance from) these nodes and weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. It finds all the matches for your search, and then calculates the similarity as 1 minus the difference between the search and the weight of the relationship. It also returns the individual likenesses that matched each photo as a map.

```
UNWIND [
{name: 'lighthouse', value: 0.856378},
{name: 'car', value: 0.17854},
{name: 'tank', value: 0.034523},
{name: 'pencil', value: 0.078902}
] AS s
MATCH (p:Photo)-[r:LOOKS_LIKE]->(l:Likeness)
WHERE l.name = s.name
RETURN p.name, SUM(1 - abs(r.weight - s.value)) AS similarity,
COLLECT({likeness:l.name, weight:r.weight, similarity: 1 - abs(r.weight - s.value)}) AS matches 
ORDER BY similarity desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by and limit clauses to return a specified number of sorted results.

Try something like this to see which five likenesses are the closest match to the treehouse photo.

```
MATCH (p:Photo {name:'treehouse'})-[r:LOOKS_LIKE]->(l:Likeness)
RETURN l.name, r.weight
ORDER BY r.weight DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I want a list of Photo nodes as the result. Not a list of Likeness nodes. So for example, the question is, which photos look %86 like a lighthouse AND 18% like a car AND %3 like a tank AND 8% like a pencil.

Comment: You did say you were looking for photos, not likenesses. I should have read more closely. I'll try again.

Comment: Any ideas? I know it sounds strange to want to find photos 86% like a lighthouse and 18% like a car but I'm actually using this for face recognition.

Comment: Do all photos have relationships to all likenesses? If there is not a photo-LOOKS_LIKE->likenesss relationship for one of the likenesses in the search, can we treat that as a weight of zero for that photo?

Comment: Each Photo node has 5 LOOKS_LIKE relationships with Likeness nodes.